# Eclipse STS: Plug-in "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted" was unable to instantiate

Tags: eclipse

I have a problem w/ Eclipse STS:

```
Plug-in "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted" was unable to instantiate class "org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted.dashboard.WelcomeDashboard".
```

Idea?

Answer (score 0):

An solution an be checking "Use Old Dashboard" from <kbd>Window > Preferences > Spring > Dashboard</kbd> , then restart eclipse.